# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' not

Tags: python, pip

I have an error when installing any package using pip

Below the snippet:

```
(venv) D:\projectodb>pip install psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joao.malebo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\joao.malebo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\projectodb\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

(venv) D:\projectodb>`
```

Comment: Try python pip install psycopg2
or python -m pip install psycopg2

Comment: Are you unable to use any `pip` command? I mean, what's the output of `pip --version` and `python3 -m pip --version`? Do you see the same exception?